# “Suggesting an edit is not allowed” when trying to submit edit after someone else edited on iOS app

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits, ios-app

I went to edit [this question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/47490/34330), but someone else edited it before I could submit my edit. I got this message which is confusing because I know I can’t suggest edits on posts with the amount of rep I have:

[image]

Instead I should have been told that someone else edited the post while I was editing.

(A similar bug was reported in 2014 but that was fixed.)

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone SE
- OS Version: Version 12.1 (Build 16B92)